# Hover effects for UL and LI classes

Tags: css, hover

My first time here so please be gentle. (oo just realised I was here last year)!

I'm trying to jazz up some rollovers with a nice fade. However the website layout doesn't use buttons but li

You can see an demo here. https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/store_v8/

I want the mouseover on the top menu and side buttons to fade to red.

I've been playing around with the transition element and a:hover:before and a:hover:after but to no avail so I thought I would come and ask you geniuses on here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show code

Answer (score 0):

looks like the current hover effect is set as this (line 87 of basic-style.css):

```
.nav > li > a:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #262626;
}
```

If you want it to transition to red instead, simply change the background-color to the value 'red' or to the hex code of the shade of red you prefer.  If you want it to 'fade', try adding a transition rule such as:

```
.nav > li > a:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color:#fff; /*white will look better on a red background than dark gray */
    transition: 300ms;
}
```

Learn more about transitions here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp